# Calling JavaScript inside spring mvc form tag

Tags: javascript, forms, spring-mvc, jsp

Hi please help me with below question

I’m working on jsp, I have situation like in that jsp we are using spring form tags, my task is to create two radio buttons when user click on radio buttons I need to display different options and I need to send user opted radio button value to my controller.

1. I wrote form:radiobutton but this is not accepting onclick/onchange attribute to call my JavaScript..!!!

2.So I wrote input tag where I can use this to call my js — with this I cant send value to controller, if I want to I can get the value from request attribute from session but I don’t want to disturb the code structure where everything coming from form tags to backend controller.

We are using jsp,spring mvc with out annotated , servlets, java8, wi

So I’m confused how to serve my purpose... please explain me thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`<form:radiobutton path="test">` (for example) will set the `name` of the generated input element to `"test"`. You can thus use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all the radio buttons with the same name. Then, loop over them and use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on each one.

```
for(const radio of document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name="test"]')){
    radio.addEventListener("change", function(e){
      // do something on change
    });
}
```